# How do I limit the number of records returned for Interbase 7.1?

Tags: sql, limit, interbase

We have an Interbase 7.1 database and I'm trying to figure out how to limit the number of records returned by the query to just 1.  I really only need to know an event code from the last record, in which the query will return hundreds of records if I cannot do some kind of limit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Needed to do something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col ROWS 1
```

Answer (score 9):

As per the accepted answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col ROWS 1
```

Will return just one result.
There are also several other row limiting options available:

> ```
> ROWS n        Returns the first n rows of the result set, or n percent if used with PERCENT
> ROWS m TO n   Returns rows m through n, inclusive or the mth to nth percent
> ROWS n BY p   Returns every pth row of the first n rows
> ```

This is particularly handy for paged results.

From the Embedded SQL Guide on the [InterBase Product Documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/) page: